# How do listen a keyboard event in dart console app?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

All examples that I found about web and *dart:html* package. Can I get keyboard or mouse events from system in a desktop console program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can read mouse events, but you can read pressed key codes from `stdin`. For this just have to switch it "raw" mode by setting both `lineMode` and `echoMode` to `false` and then listening on this stream.

Here is a simple example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io' as io;

Future main() async {
  io.stdin
    ..lineMode = false
    ..echoMode = false;
  StreamSubscription subscription;
  subscription = io.stdin.listen((List<int> codes) {
    var first = codes.first;
    var len = codes.length;
    var key;
    if (len == 1 && ((first > 0x01 && first < 0x20) || first == 0x7f)) {
      // Control code. For example:
      // 0x09 - Tab
      // 0x10 - Enter
      // 0x1b - ESC
      if (first == 0x09) {
        subscription.cancel();
      }
      key = codes.toString();
    } else if (len > 1 && first == 0x1b) {
      // ESC sequence.  For example:
      // [ 0x1b, 0x5b, 0x41 ] - Up Arrow
      // [ 0x1b, 0x5b, 0x42 ] - Down Arrow
      // [ 0x1b, 0x5b, 0x43 ] - Right Arrow
      // [ 0x1b, 0x5b, 0x44 ] - Left Arrow
      key = '${codes.toString()} ESC ${String.fromCharCodes(codes.skip(1))}';
    } else {
      key = utf8.decode(codes);
    }
    print(key);
  });
  print('Start listening');
}
```

You can also utilize [`dart_console`](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_console) package or adapt their [`readKey()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dart_console/latest/dart_console/Console/readKey.html) method that parses control and esc codes.

Comment: Thanks. This is right useful suggetions and direction. Unfortunately InelliJ run console return exception `StdinException: Error setting terminal line mode, OS Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device, errno = 25`. This is inconvenient for debugging, but this is not a problem.

Comment: @Makdir Yes, that's the issue that I couldn't solve. In IntelliJ should work `-Drun.processes.with.pty=true` VM option, but it doesn't. So, only running from real terminal works.

Comment: Is there anyway to get 'key up' events?

Comment: I filed a bug for being unable to run this from IDE: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219274483